# Properties of entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I met a problem, which says if $f$ and $g$ are all entire functions on $C$. And $f(g(z)) \in C/[- \infty，0]$,  for all $z \in C$. Then both $f$ and $g$ must be a constant.

I have no idea about how to reach this conclusion, is it about the CR equation or I need to expand them into some series?

Comment: This is false. If $f$ is constant with value $c\in \mathbb C\setminus (-\infty,0]$, then $f\circ g=f$, regardless of what $g$ is.

Comment: When you wrote $\Bbb C/[-\infty,0]$, I suppose that you meant $\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: the hypothesis implies $f\circ g$ is constant by RMT and Liouville and show that implies either $f$ or $g$ constant by general principles (eg $g$ nonconstant then takes uncountably many distinct values since it takes an open set etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct conclusion is that at least one of $f$ and $g$ is constant.  You cannot conclude that both are constant. Write $\psi= f \circ g$.  Let $h$ be a conformal   injective map from    ${\Bbb C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$ to the unit disk. This exists by the Riemann mapping theorem; for an explicit example, fix a branch of the square root function that is well defined on   ${\Bbb C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$  and take $$h(z)=\frac{\sqrt{z}-1}{\sqrt{z}+1}\, .$$ Then $h \circ \psi$ is bounded; by Liouville [1] it is constant, whence $\psi$ is also constant. If $g$ is not constant, its image must contain a continuous curve on which $f$ is constant, so $f$ equals a constant everywhere.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)